# Hard Disk has no partition map, cannot be unmounted or erased

Tags: terminal, hard-drive, usb, sudo

I have a 2Tb 2.5" hard disk that was formatted for a PC (but had errors), and have now connected it to my Mac. It is connected externally via a USB to SATA cable - I have tried two different USB to SATA cables that both work with other drives.

I first tried to erase the disk in Disk Utility (HFS+, GUID Partition Map), and got an error, saying could not write to last block. Since then the disk will now no longer show in Disk Utility, but will show in Terminal, like this:

```
    /dev/disk1 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                                                   *2.0 TB     disk11
```

Nothing else. No Partition Scheme.

Trying this:

```
diskutil eraseDisk ExFAT DiskName /dev/disk1
```

Or this:

```
diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ DiskName /dev/disk1
```

Gives:

```
Started erase on disk1
Unmounting disk
[  \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \   \  ] 

Error: -69888: Couldn't unmount disk
```

So then:

```
sudo diskutil unmountDisk force /dev/disk1
```

Gets:

```
Forced unmount of disk1 failed: at least one volume could not be unmounted
```

But then *despite* that error, the disk has been unmounted - it does not appear in diskutil list. But then repeating:

```
diskutil eraseDisk HFS+ DiskName /dev/disk1
```

Gives:

```
Could not find disk for /dev/disk1
```

There is a post with a roughly similar issue [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/235099/reformatting-disk-with-no-partition-map).

This command:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk1 bs=4096 count=8
```

Gives:

```
8+0 records in
8+0 records out
32768 bytes transferred in 0.000559 secs (58609362 bytes/sec)
```

Nothing happens for about 2 minutes, then the Terminal prompt reappears. diskutil list then does *not* show /dev/disk1

Unplugging the USB cable and reattaching it then starts the whole process as before!

Any assistance would be most welcome! I can't find an exactly equivalent case on the forum here, hence posing the new question here now.

Comment: *"...formatted for a PC (but had errors)..."*. Please add the error message(s). You can try to zero out the last blocks of the drive also (to erase a bogus 2nd GUID partition table): `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX seek=(disk_size_in_blocks(512)-64) bs=512 count=64`. Else: the drive is simply broken or the power consumption too high.

Comment: You're getting errors on a PC and on a Mac for the same piece of hardware - it's failed!  I'm not sure what the end goal is here, but I wouldn't put any data on it even if I could somehow trick the OS into writing a partition table.

Comment: Thanks @klanomath but that gives `syntax error near unexpected token '('` - and searching StackExchange for disk_size_in_blocks gives me precisely zero posts... Googling it comes up with next to nothing too.

I am afraid the PC errors were not from my machine, so I cannot post those.

@Allan - I am not giving up so soon!

Comment: @JonWorth You have to determine the disk size with `diskutil info /dev/diskX` or `sudo gpt -r -v show /dev/diskX`. Example for the latter with my internal 3TB HDD: `... blocks=5860533168 ...`. Then `... seek=(disk_size_in_blocks(512)-64) ...` is `... seek=(5860533168-64) ...` and finally: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/diskX seek=5860533104 bs=512 count=64`.